# How to insert a javascript textNode element on a newline

Tags: javascript

I insert several textNodes in javascript, and can't figure out how to separate them with carriage returns.  I've tried putting "\n", "\r", and "
" but none of them work

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 1");
element.appendChild(textNode);

textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 2");
element.appendChild(textNode);
```

I want this to appear as:

Node on line 1

Node on line 2

NOT

Node on line 1Node on line2

Any tips on how I can accomplish this ?

Comment: line breaks are ignored in HTML.  You must use a `<br>` tag to start a new line of text.

Comment: See the link below for the correct answer:
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490684/create-linebreak-on-webpage-within-a-textnode-javascript)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `<br>` to separate them as like this

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
element.appendChild(br);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Note that you can also add 'element.appendChild(br);' multiple times to your element to add multiple lines without creating the same variable.  :)

Comment: when i did this recently it didnt work. I had to use appendChild(br.cloneNode());   , refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845001/14360570

Answer (score 11):

Rendering engines don't consider *linefeed* and *carriage return* to be rendered. Better if you use a `<br />` like this:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 1");
element.appendChild(textNode);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
element.appendChild(linebreak);

var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
element.appendChild(linebreak);

textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 2");
element.appendChild(textNode);
```

Thanks [Doug Owings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794513/doug-owings). Also http://jsfiddle.net/Q8YuH/3/

Comment: The treatment of whitespace is defined in the [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1). Whitespace within markup is collapsed to a single space and elements that contain only whitespace may have it removed completely. Given that the vast majority of content on the web is HTML, and even documents with an XHTML DOCTYPE are served as HTML (and therefore treated as HTML documents by browsers) the approprlate markup for a BR element is <br>.

Answer (score 4):

To make it perfect.

```
function addText(node,text){     
         var t=text.split(/\s*<br ?\/?>\s*/i),
             i;
         if(t[0].length>0){         
           node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t[0]));
         }
         for(i=1;i<t.length;i++){
            node.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
            if(t[i].length>0){
              node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t[i]));
            }
         } 
}            
addText(document,"Line 1 <br> Line 2<br/>line 3<BR/>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 1");
element.appendChild(textNode);

var linebreak = document.createElement('<br >');
element.appendChild(lineBreak);

textNode = document.createTextNode("Node on line 2");
element.appendChild(textNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is your trying to display them separate in an HTML view and not a TEXT view in which case you need to to insert `<br />` tags between the text nodes via `document.createElement('br')` to display them on separate lines.  using `\r` or `\n` will only affect how it looks in source view.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("textContentID").innerHTML = "Text 1 <br/> Text2");
```

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript.