# Create Linebreak on webpage within a textnode - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks, createtextnode

I've seen a few responses to this question but the suggestions did not solve my output issue. A form takes input and prints to the webpage like so:

```
function init() {
var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "output";

var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    name.type = "text";
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    address.type = "text";

    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        city.type = "text";
    var state = document.getElementById("state");
        state.type = "text";
        var index = state.selectedIndex;
        var fullState = state.options[index];

    var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        zip.type = "text";

var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    email.type = "text";

var areaCode = document.getElementById("areaCode").value;
    areaCode.type = "text";
var prefix = document.getElementById("prefix").value;
    prefix.type = "text";
var suffix = document.getElementById("suffix").value;
    suffix.type = "text";

var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

/*

var courses = document.getElementById("courses").value;
    courses.type = "text";

    var aj = document.getElementById("aj").value;
        aj.type = "text";
    var asp = document.getElementById("asp").value;
        asp.type = "text";
    var php = document.getElementById("php").value;
        php.type = "text";
*/

var br = document.createElement('br');



var printName = document.createTextNode("Name: " + name + " ");
var printEmail = document.createTextNode("Email: " + email + " ");
var printPhone = document.createTextNode("Phone: " + areaCode + "-" + prefix + "-" + suffix);
var printAddress = document.createTextNode("Address: " + address + " " + city + " " + fullState.text + " " + zip);
var printGender = document.createTextNode("Gender: " + gender + " ");
//var printCourses = document.createTextNode("Courses Taken:" + courses + " ");



div.appendChild(printName);
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(printEmail);
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(printPhone);
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(printAddress);
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(printGender);
div.appendChild(br);
//div.appendChild(printCourses);
div.appendChild(br);

var output = document.getElementById("output");

if(output) {
    output.parentNode.replaceChild(div, output);
} else {
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
}
```

The output is still just one continuous line on the webpage despite having created the line break element. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
var br = document.createElement('br');
```

you have a reference to a SINGLE element.  So when you do this:

```
div.appendChild(printName);
div.appendChild(br);
div.appendChild(printEmail);
div.appendChild(br);
```

You are saying "add the `printName` element, then add this `<br>` element after it.  Now, create the `printEmail` element, then MOVE that same `<br>` element after it."

So in the end, you still have just ONE `<br>` element, after everything else.

The fix that probably involves the least code change is something like:

```
function br() {
    return document.createElement('br');
}

div.appendChild(printName);
div.appendChild(br());
```

Comment: Ahhh and so by the end my line break is after the last element, and totally useless. Making it into a callable function is a great fix. Thanks!