# Document.createElement("br") not working with multiple calls to appendChild

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
var x = document.createElement("p");
var br1 = document.createElement('br');
var br2 = document.createElement('br');
var t5 = document.createTextNode("CSE");
var t6 = document.createTextNode("EEE");
x.appendChild(t5);
x.appendChild(br1);
x.appendChild(t6);
x.appendChild(br2);

document.getElementById("new").appendChild(x);
```

The output should look like

```
CSE

EEE
```

but now the output is `CSEEEE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert a line break with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272623/how-to-insert-a-line-break-with-javascript)

Comment: Answer to a similar question: "If you call appendChild passing in an element that's already in the DOM, it's moved, not copied." ([How to add multiple divs with appendChild?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14910214/2314737))

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is with the `br` element you created. It is unique. So at first when you append it to its place in the DOM, it sits in between the t5 and t6 element. However, when you append the br element a second time, it places it in a different location in the DOM and that is why you see the result of CSEEEE followed by only 1 br element.

You should either omit the last one, or clone the br element.

```js
var x = document.createElement("p");
var br = document.createElement('br');
var t5=document.createTextNode("CSE");
var t6=document.createTextNode("EEE");
x.appendChild(t5);
x.appendChild(br);
x.appendChild(t6);
x.appendChild(br.cloneNode());

document.getElementById("new").appendChild(x);
```

```html
<div id="new">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't reuse the same elemnt

```
var x = document.createElement("p");
var t5=document.createTextNode("CSE");
var t6=document.createTextNode("EEE");
x.appendChild(t5);
x.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
x.appendChild(t6);
x.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

document.getElementById("new").appendChild(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **two** `<br>`

```
var x = document.createElement("p");
var br1 = document.createElement('br');
var br2 = document.createElement('br');
var t5 = document.createTextNode("CSE");
var t6 = document.createTextNode("EEE");
x.appendChild(t5);
x.appendChild(br1);
x.appendChild(t6);
x.appendChild(br2);

document.getElementById("new").appendChild(x);
```